Why isn't MSVC notifying of an error here?
I had some problems with order of destructors being called on static objects. I wrote this as a test to verify that the error checking is working:
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct
{
    int a, b, c, d, f;

    ~MyStruct();
};

MyStruct my_object;

std::vector<int> array{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };


MyStruct::~MyStruct() { array.push_back(4); }


int main()
{
    return 0;
}

On Compiler Explorer there's the following behaviour:
With address sanitizer off:
Clang: 
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV

GCC: 
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV

MSVC: No error.

With address sanitizer on:
Clang: 
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free 

GCC:
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free

MSVC: No error

With GCC and Clang the command was -fsanitize=address and with MSVC it was /fsanitize=address. On my compiler at home MSVC too doesn't give any error. I'm trying to make it so that errors like this are caught. What can I do? It's interesting because normally the sanitizer on MSVC is good, and it seems to catch this type of problem, but it isn't catching this.

I guess, it's a false negative, a bug in the MSVC sanitizer. You could report it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/how-to-report-a-problem-with-the-visual-cpp-toolset?view=msvc-170

Even though the sanitizers are supposedly the same across compilers, I've seen cases where e.g. GCC fails to report something and Clang reports correctly. I guess it has to do with how well they annotate the source code with the ASAN calls?

A blatant use-after-free. But it's also a consequence the Static initialization order fiasco.

@Red.Wave not a static init order fiasco in the example posted here. Within a translation unit/file the order is deterministic. Edit: I guess you're right that it is! An intentional one!

@Red.Wave No fiasco here.  The fiasco come into play once there is multiple TU's and they depend on each other

@NathanOliver I had the same initial thought as you, and while you're right, I think RedWave was specifically talking about the effect of the static init fiasco, which is that init/destruction order results in UB

@AndyG only across TUs.  Within a TU globals (namespace objects with static storage duration) are constructed in order of declaration and destructed in reverse order.  More details here Dynamic initialization.

@AndyG I get that, but the static initialization order fiasco is specifically about using static objects from one TU to construct other static objects in another TU. Had the OP put the same code in main the same thing would happen.

@RichardCritten I know, that's what I said! Again, you and NathanOliver are right, it's not truly the static initialization order fiasco as stated, but it's a convenient hand-wave to talk about UB as a result of initialization of statics, and I choose to believe that's what RedWave meant.

Wonder if MSVC looked a little deeper at the code, realized there was no observable behaviour, and optimized it all out.


This is undefined behavior. Undefined means undefined, no diagnostics are required. 2. Program returned: 3221225781 - missing libraries. The compiler explorer is not configured for running address sanitizer on Windows.


The snippet is blatant use-after-free.  (Good MRE, thank you!)  Either the ASan missed it for MSVC, or MSVC optimized out would would otherwise have been use-after-free.  If it did get optimized out, no use-after-free occurred.  Sanitizers can only notice things at runtime that occur. (And, alas, sanitizers don't catch all runtime errors; just an best-effort subset of runtime errors.)

Cross references between static duration objects is always prone to creating problems. In theory, C++ module can prevent inter-TU dependence by preventing circular module cross-references. It also seems possible to detect such violations inside any single TU. I think tool-chains must act a bit more aggressive on this one, and at least default to warnings.

@Red.Wave I know this will be seen as bad, but to avoid many of these problems I simply created something like a LeakingOptional. You control when to construct into it and no destructors are called. Rust doesn't call static constructors, so I don't see why this is bad. I could just not have these things as statics, but why not? It just simplifies my code.

@Zebrafish the main issue about static initialization (in single TU) is circular reference in ctor/dtor. Most other problems can be avoided with Meyer's singletons; it's implemented like an optional behind the scenes. But circular cross references at ctor/dtor can still cause problems. Modern modules can prevent cross module troubles by disallowing circular inter-modular references, but single TU have not been considered yet.
